# 404 when doing safe-upgrade in lucid 64 box?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, aptitude

Why I see 404 when doing `sudo aptitude safe-upgrade` in my lucid 64 box?

```
deploy@li167-251:~$ sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reading extended state information      
Initializing package states... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apache2 apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-threaded-dev apache2-utils apache2.2-bin apache2.2-common apt apt-utils 
  base-files binutils bzip2 dpkg dpkg-dev gzip ifupdown krb5-multidev language-pack-en language-pack-en-base 
  language-selector-common libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-dev libavahi-client3 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common3 
  libbz2-1.0 libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev libc6-i686 libcups2 libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev 
  libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-dev libgssapi-krb5-2 libgssrpc4 libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-common libgtk2.0-dev 
  libk5crypto3 libkadm5clnt-mit7 libkadm5srv-mit7 libkdb5-4 libkrb5-3 libkrb5-dev libkrb5support0 
  libldap-2.4-2 libldap2-dev libmysqlclient-dev libmysqlclient16 libnotify-dev libnotify1 libpam-modules 
  libpam-runtime libpam0g libparted0debian1 libpng12-0 libpng12-dev libpq-dev libpq5 libssl-dev libssl0.9.8 
  libtiff4 libudev0 libusb-0.1-4 linux-libc-dev mountall mysql-client mysql-client-5.1 mysql-client-core-5.1 
  mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server-core-5.1 openssh-client openssh-server openssl 
  parted python-apt sudo tzdata udev upstart ureadahead wget xulrunner-1.9.2 xulrunner-1.9.2-dev 
The following packages are RECOMMENDED but will NOT be installed:
  colibri debhelper fakeroot hicolor-icon-theme libatk1.0-data libglib2.0-data libgtk2.0-bin 
  libhtml-template-perl manpages-dev notification-daemon notify-osd ssl-cert xauth xfce4-notifyd 
88 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 85.8MB of archives. After unpacking 1712kB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y
Writing extended state information... Done
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main libpam-modules 1.1.1-2ubuntu5 [358kB]
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main base-files 5.0.0ubuntu20.10.04.2 [70.2kB]
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main gzip 1.3.12-9ubuntu1.1 [102kB]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main libc-bin 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.37 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main libc6 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.37 80]
Err http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main libc6-i686 2.11.1-0ubuntu7.2
.........
```

Comment: `sudo aptitude update` did the work.

Answer (score 3):

[HTTP 404](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404)
The 404 or Not Found error message is a HTTP standard response code indicating that the client was able to communicate with the server, but the server could not find what was requested. 404 errors should not be confused with "server not found" or similar errors, in which a connection to the destination server could not be made at all. A 404 error indicates that the requested resource may be available again in the future.

Are you really trying to figure out what is happening here?